# Minimize number of WebDAV requests on Mac

Tags: macos, http, ms-word, http-headers, webdav

I'm writing a WebDAV server and encountered the following problem. Mac OS X clients (Finder, Microsoft Office for Mac) generate too many different requests. I had the same problem with Microsoft Word for Windows, but after setting [custom headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250217.aspx):

```
Ms-Author-Via: DAV
```

Microsoft Word started using much more limited number of requests. Here's how 
Microsoft Word editing session looks on Windows (and Windows or Linux with LibreOffice):

```
PROPFIND
GET
LOCK (windows only)
PUT
UNLOCK (windows only)
PROPFIND (linux only)
```

Mac OS Finder and Office for Mac however generate a lot of additional requests, namely:

- Generation of temporary files
- Generation of temporary folders
- Moving them around

Is there some header combination that reduces a number of requests in Mac OS X?

Comment: I think [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them) will be of interest to you. Sadly, it doesn't look too good.

Comment: @DaSourcerer yes, getting rid of dot and underscore files would be nice too.

Comment: Note that you can avoid a lot of this by mounting the WebDAV URL into Finder via ocsmount, Mountain Duck or Transmit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, it sadly looks a lot like this were beyond the powers of some HTTP headers. It is also a somewhat known issue as [this owncloud issue](https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/17732) and [this document](http://sabre.io/dav/clients/finder/) in the sabre DAV documentation shows. [Apple's solution](https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT1629) to this is by disabling temporary file creation altogether through the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

However, it sounds like you will have to cater to the needs of many clients outside of your control, which makes this impractical. Owncloud has tackled this by [mocking successfull `LOCK`/`UNLOCK`s](https://github.com/owncloud/core/pull/20505) for finder, turning these requests essentially into NOPs. A less subtle approach were to [forcefully prevent creation of these files](https://gist.github.com/jirutka/5380770) in the first place. On a personal note, I feel a mix of Owncloud's approach combined with a [`.metadata_never_index` file](http://www.filetypehelp.com/purpose-files-metadataneverindex-file-extension/) were most promising and largely free of undesired side-effects.

Comment: .metadata_never_index file prevents the creation of  .DS_Store files but does not prevent a creation of ._<file> files for office documents. Thank you.

Comment: @rfg that [can be switched off](https://serverfault.com/a/457769) but is difficult to address through the means of WebDAV/HTTP. You can prevent the creation of these files, but that may result into the actual files being rendered read-only (from the perspective of Office, that is).